# Correct way to create a theme from scratch in Angular 8 (Bootstrap)

Tags: angular8

I am new to Angular 8. I am confused in creating the theme for Angular 8. I searched for this in many site but they are using the jQuery and Popper.js. So, jQuery is the reason that's why I am confused.
What is the correct way to implement the bootstrap theme in Angular. Can we implement it without using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Install Bootstrap

run `npm install bootstrap`

> 2. Add bootstrap.scss to your angular.json file

projects->yourproject->architect->options->styles Add

```
"styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"]
```

> 3. If you are after JS interactions like dropdowns..etc , install ng-bootstrap

run `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Doco: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/examples

*Done.* No JQuery or Popper.js required